# Use JPA in Java SE application with support for transactions

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, jpa-2.0

I am trying to develop a small program that uses JPA, but can run without an application server, i.e. as a regular Java SE application.

AFAIK, for JavaEE the application server takes care of starting and ending database transactions. Now my problem is that I get this error from some internal code using JPA:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1171)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1332)
    at <see below>
```

The code causing this exception is equivalent to this:

```
String persistenceUnitName; // actually comes from some config file
EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName).createEntityManager();
entityManager.flush();  // exception is thrown here
```

I cannot change that code, so it relies on a transaction being automagically started.

Wrapping the call to the above code in a custom transaction like this:

```
String persistenceUnitName; // same persistence unit name
EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName).createEntityManager();
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
callAboveCode();
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

does not help. the call to the factory's `createEntityManager()` returns a new entity manager each time, resulting in a different persistence context I suppose.

Is there a way to get automatic transactioning, similar to running JPA in an application server, in a Java SE application?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that explicit transaction in the second approach doesn't work? Do you still see the error?

Comment: Yes, same result

Comment: The code causing the exception should definitely be changed: it relies on a transaction being handled automatically, as if it ran in a Java EE or Spring context, but it creates an EntityManagerFactory using the Persistence class, as if it ran in a Java SE context. So, for both contexts, it is wrong. Use Spring, and change the faulty code.

Comment: It actually uses a mixture of CDI (injects @any entity manager instance, which is always empty in my case) and manual creation using the Persistence class if none were found. Looks like it tries to support both Java EE and Java SE

Comment: If you are using a RESOURCE_LOCAL transaction (default for JavaSE) then you clearly have to call `getTransaction().begin()`. I know of one JPA provider that allows non-transactional persistence operations (and you're not using it), but not part of the JPA spec

Answer (score 2):

In SE you have to be careful only using one instance of EntityManager in the whole application. Use a singleton ore something similar for managing that instance.

You also have to manage transaction "manually" - like:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(anyobject);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```